# Partial Specialization of Variable Templates

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-specialization, variable-templates

I know that I can partially specialize class templates, and I know that I cannot partially specify function templates.

What about [variable templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template)? I can't find documentation on whether they can be partially specialized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, according to [[temp.arg.template]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#2):

> Any **partial specializations** associated with the primary class template or primary **variable template** are considered when a specialization based on the template template-parameter is instantiated. ...

And to [[temp.expl.spec]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#7):

> ... the placement of **partial specialization declarations of** class templates, **variable templates**, member class templates of non-template classes, static data member templates of non-template classes, member class templates of class templates, etc. ...

It also mentioned in [[constraints.namespace.std]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#namespace.std-3):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares an explicit or **partial specialization of** any standard library **variable template**, except where explicitly permitted by the specification of that variable template.

---

Not to mention that all major compilers (Clang, GCC and MSVC) have no problems with them:

```
template <int x, int y>
constexpr int foo = -1;

template <>
constexpr float foo<1, 0> = 1.0;

template <int x>
constexpr double foo<1, x> = 1.1;

int main()
{
    static_assert(foo<0, 0> == -1, "");
    static_assert(foo<0, 1> == -1, "");
    static_assert(foo<1, 0> == 1.0, "");
    static_assert(foo<1, 1> == 1.1, "");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/R1c1zo

Comment: Welp, it looks like I'd just put my angle brackets in the wrong place. Thanks, I'll accept shortly.

Comment: The third quote (from [constraints.namespace.std]/3) should emphasize **standard library**, as that's the salient point there.